# Cheerio returning non-existing matches?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I am trying to scrape the contents from a website that has a very chaotic structure and many different styles of content in the same document and this is driving me nuts...

If anyone finds a more reasonable way to get the contents is also welcome, as I am a complete newbie to all js thing.

The code I have is returning everything I need but it is also getting results of non-existing elements in the document.

The HTML is basically this:

```
    <div class="section" id="unit-tasks">
      <h4 class="section__title">
        Tasks
        <ul class="course--tasks-check-list">
          <li class="task-item">
            <div class="task-item__anchor">
              <h3 class="task-item__title">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.<i class="fa"></i><span class="badge">Easy Task</span>
              </h3>
              <div class="task-item__description">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                <p>Unde velit tenetur quia architecto tempora molestiae?</p>
                <div class="image-item">
                  <img src="image.jpg" />
                </div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum <a href="someplace.html">dolor, sit amet</a> consectetur <a href="elsewhere.html"> adipisicing elit.</a> Quis, facilis?</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="task-item">
            <div class="task-item__anchor">
              <h3 class="task-item__title">
                Explicabo mollitia molestias illum maxime.<i class="fa"></i><span class="badge">Medium task</span>
              </h3>
              <div class="task-item__description">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                <div class="btn-toolbar">
                  <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" href="sendhome.html">Lorem!</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </h4>
    </div>
```

I need to get from this an object that is something like:

```
{ 'tasks': {
           0: {
              title: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
              contents: {
                        0: {
                           type: 'text',
                           content: 'Lorem .... '
                           }
                        1: {
                           type: 'image',
                           src: 'image.jpg'
                           }
                        2: {
                           type: 'text',
                           content: 'Yada yada yad',
                           links: {
                                  0: {
                                     linkText: 'yada',
                                     href: 'someplace.html'
                                     },
                                  1: {
                                     linkText: 'yad',
                                     href: 'someotherplace.html'
                                     }
                                  },
                           },
                        }
                }
           }
}
```

The problem is that my node.js code with cheerio is giving me the object I want, but its is also giving a lot of { type: 'image', src: undefined } items too.

Can anyone give me some light on this? The JS code I have at the moment is:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const fs = require('fs');

const chapTasks = {}

function getTasks(){
    let taskCount = 0
    if ($('.task-item').length) {
        $('.task-item').each( function() {
            chapTasks[taskCount] = {}
            chapTasks[taskCount]['contents'] = {}
            taskTitle = $(this).find('.task-item__title').html()
            taskTitle = taskTitle.slice(0, taskTitle.indexOf('<')).trim()
            chapTasks[taskCount]['title'] = taskTitle
            let contentCount = 0
            $(this).find('.task-item__description').children().each( function() {
                let tag = $(this).get(0).tagName
                if (tag == 'p') {
                    chapTasks[taskCount]['contents'][contentCount] = {
                        type : 'text',
                        content : $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim()
                    }
                    if ($(this).find('a').length){
                        linkCount = 0
                        chapTasks[taskCount]['contents'][contentCount]['links'] = {}
                        $(this).find('a').each( function() {
                            chapTasks[taskCount]['contents'][contentCount]['links'][linkCount] = {
                                'linkText' : $(this).text(),
                                'href' : $(this).attr('href')
                            }
                            linkCount += 1
                        })
                    }
                    contentCount += 1
                }
                if ($(this).find('div.image-item > img')) {
                    chapTasks[taskCount]['contents'][contentCount] = {
                        type : 'image',
                        'src' : $(this).find('img').attr('src')
                    }
                    contentCount += 1
                }
            })
            taskCount += 1
        })
     }
     console.dir(chapTasks, { depth: null })
}

getTasks()
```

If needed, I tried my best to add the code to a codepen: https://codepen.io/mendoncajoao/pen/ZEMXMeV

Comment: In your codepen, you load the HTML into Cheerio, then dump it to a string and load it into Cheerio a second time. I'm curious--why?

Comment: The code is not being run in codepen... The code is just a small part of another big project.

I placed the thing there just to maybe make it more readable than here...

Comment: OK, thanks--just making sure you're not doing that in your big project unless there's good reason to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were doing this it would look something like:

```
let contents = $('h3').get().reduce((acc, h3) => {
  let title = $(h3).text()
  let ps = $(h3).find("+ div p").get().map(p => {
    return {
      type: "text",
      content: $(p).text()
    }
  })
  let imgs = $(h3).find("+ div img").get().map(img => {
    return {
      type: "image",
      content: $(img).attr('src')
    }
  })
  acc[title] = [...ps, ...imgs]
}, {})
```

Comment: Wow!! I completely forgot about the "+" selector! I will check your code tomorrow, but just the reminder of that selector will save me a lot of work! Thanks!

Comment: you're welcome. fyi it's only available on newer cheerio versions

Comment: I will check the documentation with more attention and that shouldnt be a problem as I am not worried about earlier versions at the moment... if anything changes in the future I might look for an alternative way to get the contents and maybe scrap the cheerio lib as a whole. Thanks for the light!!